# Why is Wake-On-LAN not working on my MacBook Pro with LogMeIn?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard

Hey guys, as of this date (2011-05-24) I have the:

- Latest version of LogMeIn Free running on my MacBook Pro
- The Latest version of Snow Leopard
- I have the mid 2009 17" unibody MacBook Pro

On my MacBook I have the "wake up from lan" box checked in the energy savings settings.

My MacBook is also plugged in, and the Ethernet cable is plugged in. I always leave the Airport on on the macbook so that's on too.

It's now in "sleep" and the lid is closed.

When I go to the LogMeIn dashboard it says offline... is this because the Wake-On-Lan is not working? Has anyone had this issue or know how to fix it?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for the Macbook to go out of sleep when the lid is closed and no external display and input devices are connected. Your best option therefore is to keep the lid open.

Comment: Here's a discussion to back this up further: http://www.mackb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/mac/16622/using-a-Macbook-Pro-headless-with-the-lid-closed

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox for wake-on-LAN only allows the ethernet interface to respond to what's called a "magic packet" that will then cause the system to wake up. I don't know what the LogMeIn dashboard looks like, but if it's just a status report for the other computers on your local network, then it is reporting the state of your MacBook accurately. If the Dashboard has the capability of sending the magic packet, then that is a step you will need to execute before the machine comes back online.

If it doesn't do this, you'll need an extra tool to send the wakeup call.

Just making sure, you're doing all of this from within your local network, right?

Comment: +1 Hi nreilingh, thanks for your response. No, different network. Logmein claims itmsupports this feature. You access throughh the web interface and then it's supposed to wake the machine up... Doesn't seem to be working though

Answer (score 0):

LogMeIn specify another requirement that you may not have met:

"Please also confirm that at least one other LogMeIn host on the same LAN is online and available"

I presume this is required so that LogMeIn can communicate with that "live" host and send the magic packet from that host to the Mac that you want to wake up.

Details found here: http://community.logmein.com/t5/Free/Wake-on-LAN/td-p/31061

Comment: Also see the rest of that thread re: the free 'wakeup' program which can WOL your sleeping machine (without needing help from another machine on your network).