# SSH to sleeping MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, ssh

If my MacBook (2011 MBA) is sleeping (with the lid closed) is it possible to connect to it via SSH?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Wake-On-LAN not working on my MacBook Pro with LogMeIn?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/why-is-wake-on-lan-not-working-on-my-macbook-pro-with-logmein)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no, it is not possible to go out of sleep with the lid closed as mentioned by XQYZ at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15564/8289